# Как построить не реляционную модель со связями

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, nosql

## Задача:

Построить модель в MongoDB для базы где будут храниться артисты, альбомы, песни и пользователи со связью с песнями. В качестве языка программирования использую Python + pymongo

---

#### Вопросы:

1. Как связать песню с пользователем?
2. Как зная песню получить список всех пользователей который добавили песню?
3. Подходит данная модель для данных задач?

---

#### В голову приходит такая модель:

Список песен:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "author": "name",
    "albums": [
        {
            "name": "Albums name",
            "songs": [
                { 
                    "name": "Name song",
                    "text": "Song text",
                },
                { "..." }
            ],
        },
        { "..." }
    ]
}
```

Пользователь:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "Иван Иванов",
    "trek_id": [
        "id_1", "id_2"
    ]
}
```

> я понимаю что вопрос слишком обширный, но начинаю изучать NoSQL и голова не способна построить не реляционную модель и представляет все в реляционном виде.

Comment: Видимо, "нереляционная", а не "не религиозная"...

Comment: @Qwertiy да, именно, спасибо.

Comment: по описанному в вопросе совершенно невозможно ничего сказать, потому как для ответа на вопрос необходимо знать все детали, что с какими объектами будет происходить в системе. причем до мелочей, потому что какая нибудь мелочь, вроде подсчета какого нибудь рейтинга может вдруг оказаться невозможной и структуру придется пересматривать. или даже менять БД. https://habrahabr.ru/post/231213/

Comment: И кстати я совершенно не понимаю, что такое trek_id у пользователя, на что он ссылается, если сами треки зарыты глубоко в иерархию под автором.